# What is the cross-linguistic tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I don't quite get the usage of the [cross-linguistic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-linguistic). Does it mean that the question concerns more than one language? In that case, aren't questions by default cross-linguistic? Is it something like "language agnostic" in SO or similar xxx-agnostic tags in other SEs?

Also it would be very nice if answerers also propose tag wiki content for this tag.

Comment: I also am not sure what I should use that tag for. [But when I google for the terms synchronic, diachronic, and cross-linguistic](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=synchronic+diachronic+cross-linguistic) hoping to find some synonymity I actually find instead that the three terms do seem to be used as a set by linguists. I still don't know what it all means though!

Answer (score 3):

Many answers in linguistics will be informed by cross-linguistic comparison; it is a major methodological tenet of the discipline.  Given that, I think we should think of when having a separate [cross-linguistic](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-linguistic) tag will be useful for the community; I propose the following guideline:

> The cross-linguistic tag is for questions that specifically ask for comparisons across (as opposed to within) languages or language families.

So a question about a phenomenon in one language would not carry this tag, even though its answers could of course make reference to other languages.  More subtly, a (hypothetically existing) question about the development of periphrastic verb paradigms in Romance would not bear this tag, since it is about *one* process in the Romance family.  A question asking to compare/contrast Romance and Germanic periphrastic tenses would have the tag.

Of the questions currently tagged cross-linguistic, I think only [Is the "ll" in Albanian like the sounds in other languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/449/is-the-ll-in-albanian-like-the-sounds-in-other-languages) and [Are there languages with other spatial deixis besides "here", "there" and "over there"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/378/are-there-languages-with-other-spatial-deixis-besides-here-there-and-over-t) meet this criterion.  Other not-currently-tagged candidates for this criterion (from the first few pages of recent questions) are:

- [What is LOLspeak, and does it have equivalents in languages other than English?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/107/what-is-lolspeak-and-does-it-have-equivalents-in-languages-other-than-english)
- [Is the sound "ř" unique to Czech?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/377/is-the-sound-r-unique-to-czech)
- ["Overabundant nouns" in Italian: do they exist in other languages?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/244/overabundant-nouns-in-italian-do-they-exist-in-other-languages)

Comment: You're one of the most capable here so I'd like to encourage you to edit the tag's wiki and retag the questions. They're the sorts of things we're expected to do to improve the site's usefulness.

Comment: @hippietrail, I didn't want to go on a retagging rampage in case my idea was judged off-the-wall.  But if no one howls in protest after a day or two, I'll do it.